# Event Registry design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, grails, groovy

I have a list of events that i need to fire when a user takes an action and an event manager that fires these events.

Originally i used to fire the events explicitly in this way

```
EventManager.publish(new SendNotificationEvent())
```

Then i wanted  to change that to something like

```
EventManager.publishSendNotificationEvent()
```

To do that, i need to dynamically load the class "SendNotificationEvent", instantiate it and fire the event. Dealing with ClassLoder dynamically uses reflection, slow and a pain to deal with. So I thought of registering the event when the root class Event is loaded

```
Event {
 Map registry = [:]
 static {
   registry["SendNotificationEvent"] = SendNotificationEvent.class
 }

 Class get(String key) {
    return registry[key]
 }
}
```

and change the event manage to resolve the event class through Event

```
EventManager {
 Class $static_methodMissing (String name, args) {
    def event Event.get(name-"fire").metaClass.invokeConstructor(args)
    fire(event)
 }
}
```

Is this a good approach, is there a design pattern that i can use to do this better or should I just live with ClassLoader pain and make it work ...

- ken

Comment: Why did you drop the explicit EventManager.publish(new SendNotificationEvent()) ?

Answer (score 0):

I like your first way better (and I have to agree with FabrizioM's comment - why?)

I like `EventManager.publish(new SendNotificationEvent())` because the `EventManager` doesn't know anything about the events; this will make your system much easier to maintain (etc).

Coding is like a form of exercise: if it starts to hurt you should stop.